# Making a Custom Camera, getting a " Thread 1: signal SIGBRT" ERROR in my App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, camera

I'm making a custom camera. I have 2 view controllers for the camera (one for the actual capture and another for a photo preview). Here is the code in each, I have reviewed it but don't find anything wrong! My XCODE project is a single view with CoreData enabled. EDIT: I have already added the appropriate Info.Plist camera permisions.

Below is my ViewController for taking the photo:

```
 import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?

    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    var cameraPreviewlayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    var image: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }

    func setupDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)

        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }
        }

        currentCamera = backCamera
    }

    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func setupPreviewLayer(){
        cameraPreviewlayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewlayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewlayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        cameraPreviewlayer?.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewlayer!, at: 0)
    }

    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    @IBAction func CameraButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

       // performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto_Segue", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showPhoto_Segue" {
            let previewVC = segue.destination as! PreviewViewController
            previewVC.image = self.image
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

}

extension ViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            print(imageData)
            image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto_Segue", sender: nil)
        }
    }


}
```

This is the code for my Preview where my error occurs when I press the Cancel or Save button for the capture the user just took:

```
    import UIKit

class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView!

    var image: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        photo.image = self.image

    }

    @IBAction func cancelButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

I have not changed or added any code inside the AppDelegate. This is in XCODE 9 and Swift 4. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine, you just forgot to ask permission for the camera use in the info.plist file, add this "Privacy - Camera Usage Description"

Comment: Well then my friend in order to help you more i will need more info or you can share the whole project, because in my machine it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you already updated .plist file you should check Camera Usage Permission.

```swift
func checkPermissions() {
    let authStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    switch authStatus {
    case .authorized:
        setupCamera()
    case .denied:
        alertPromptToAllowCameraAccessViaSetting()
    default:
        // Not determined fill fall here - after first use, when is't neither authorized, nor denied
        // we try to use camera, because system will ask itself for camera permissions
        setupCamera()
    }
}

func alertPromptToAllowCameraAccessViaSetting() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Camera access required to...", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .cancel) { (alert) -> Void in
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
    })

    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Where should I paste this code?/What should I do with this code?

Comment: You should use this code on camera view controller.